# How to save a pdf from MS word with non-searchable text

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I want to generate pdf from MS Word, but the pdf format should be somehow like a scanned document (i.e., pdf as image, and all text is not searchable).

At the moment, I have 2 solutions:

1. print out the Word Document and scan back to computer as pdf (but it is a kind of wasting paper)
2. install some pdf printer tools that is available on internet (but I do not have the admin right for installation)

Therefore, is there any other way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: The case is like I print out the word file with paper, and then scan back to computer, so that no text could be searched since the file is in image format

Answer (score 0):

Use an online converter such as https://www.zamzar.com to convert your document to multipage tiff. That should get rid of any text and leave you with a file that just contains images.

Then either print that to .pdf if you have the appropriate printer driver on your operating system, or use the same or another service to convert the .tif to a .pdf.